# Testing Switch components with Detox - tapping affects previous toHaveValue() test

Tags: react-native, integration-testing, e2e-testing, detox

I'm trying to create an integration test for a page with a switch toggle.

```
<Switch style={settingsStyles.switch}
  value={this.props.value}
  onValueChange={this.onValueChange}
  testID={`FirstToggle`}/>
```

I started writing my test like this:

```
let toggle = element(by.id(`FirstToggle`));
await expect(toggle).toHaveValue(`0`);
```

And it works fine for the default value. However, I also wanted to make sure that after tapping, the value changes and remains changed. 
So I updated my tests to look like this:

```
let toggle = element(by.id(`FirstToggle`));
await expect(toggle).toHaveValue(`0`);

await toggle.tap();

toggle = element(by.id(`FirstToggle`));
await expect(toggle).toHaveValue(`1`);
```

The problem is, my tests now fail when doing the *first* assertion that the toggle is not checked!

```
Failed: [Error: Error: An assertion failed.
    Exception with Assertion: {
      "Assertion Criteria":  "assertWithMatcher:((respondsToSelector(isAccessibilityElement) && isAccessibilityElement) && accessibilityValue('0'))",
      "Element Matcher":  "((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('FirstToggle'))) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('FirstToggle'))))))"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried using `waitFor` when doing the assertions, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I'm using Detox 9.0.5.